# Is the data exchange with a https endpoint, encrypted?

Tags: apex, heroku, apex-webservice, callout

I am developing in Salesforce an app, that communicates with a bunch of web services in Heroku. Till here, every thing is fine, but now we want to be sure that the data that we exchange is encrypted, so my question is: If the services exposed from Heroku, are accessed with https protcol, is there any need to register in our Salesforce instance any certificate, so we could use SSL protocol to encrypt our messagges?

Note: The Heroku App, is using the standard domain, [myAppName].herokuapp.com.

Thank you!
Endrit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku automatically provides a SSL certificate for standard subdomains. As long as you are using HTTPS, your app's communications are already encrypted with no extra effort. In other words, as long as your code calls an endpoint that starts with https://, you're good to go.